# polyhedra property proof

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, polyhedra

So I'm trying to understand this statement, which apparently is true...

Let $P=\{ x \in R^n | Ax =b,x \geq 0 \}$ be a polyhedron with matrix $A\in R^{(n-1) \times n}%$ and $rank(A)=n-1$.

P has at most two vertices

I can see this in $R^2$, since it would be just a line and line hast to vertices. but im having a trouble to see it in the general case.. why should it be true? how would it work for n=3?

Comment: sorry it should be at most two vertices* just corrected the statement. but this wouldnt be true for n=2?

Comment: The dimension is $n-rank(A)$ hence $n-n+1=1$. Since it is one dimensional it has at most two vertices. Either it is a line segment (two endpoints) or it is one endpoint and is unbounded on the other side. Since we have $x>= 0$ it cannot be the case that we have a line with no endpoints

Comment: Yeah this makes more sense, still the explanation just needs the dimension. I made a new comment and hope it is understandable

Comment: yes thanks a lot!